# Is there anything like batch update in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

In Java we have batch execution like the java code below:

```
Statement statement = null;
statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.addBatch("update people set firstname='John' where id=123");
statement.addBatch("update people set firstname='Eric' where id=456");
statement.addBatch("update people set firstname='May'  where id=789");

int[] recordsAffected = statement.executeBatch();
```

how to do the same in rails ActiveRecord?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches ?

Comment: For example i have table called User and it has column points. I have this values IDs[1,2,3,9,10,15,20] corresponding Points[2,3,5,1,1,5,5] to be updated in database at one shot. Like update user set points = (2,3,5,1,1,5,5) where user id = (1,2,3,9,10,15,20) but this is not a correct sql command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can give this a try. Seems like what you're after.

```
# Updating multiple records:
people = { 1 => { "first_name" => "David" }, 2 => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }
Person.update(people.keys, people.values)
```

Quoted: https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/01/03/updating-multiple-records-at-the-same-time-rails-activerecord/

To fit the post requirements, it translates to:

```
people = { 
  123 => { "firstname" => "John" },
  456 => { "firstname" => "Eric" },
  789 => { "firstname" => "May" }
}
Person.update(people.keys, people.values)
```

Please note that translating the above into SQL still yields multiple queries

Comment: Taught me something as well

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Rails 6**, you can now perform bulk update using `upsert_all` method for exemple.

More details available there: https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/bulk-insert-support-in-rails-6

Be aware that `unique_by` option is not supported when the database is MySQL but it works great for Postgresql.