# Ruby on Rails inefficient database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My Rails app has the following conditions:

Each `Style` has many `Bookings`

Each `Booking` has a single `warehouse` value, and a single `netbooked` value

I need to update the `warehouse_netbooked` column of every `Style` with a hash containing the total `netbooked` sum for each `warehouse` across all of the style's bookings.

My current code works, but is way too slow (each iteration is taking ~0.5s, and there are thousands of styles):

```
    def assign_warehouse_bookings
      warehouses = ["WH1","WH2","WH3"]
      Style.all.each do |s|
        style_warehouse_bookings = Hash.new
        warehouses.each do |wh|
          total_netbooked = s.bookings.where(warehouse: wh).sum(:netbooked)
          style_warehouse_bookings[wh] = total_netbooked
        end
        s.update(warehouse_netbooked: "#{style_warehouse_bookings}")
      end
    end
```

Comment: I'm curious about the syntax you're using (slamming a hash into an `update` statement) but it seems like you should be able to build a single `update` query here, rather than running the *thousands* of queries you're currently running to load three different `sum`s for each style.

Comment: Can you identify why its slow before trying to make it faster? I would start by looking at the queries that are executed and see if any of them are inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here a small change to your code to avoid to do many queries following @eric-duminil advise

```
@styles = Style.includes(:bookings)
@styles.each do |s|
  style_warehouse_bookings = Hash.new
    warehouses.each do |wh|
      total_netbooked = s.bookings.map {|book| book.warehouse.eql?(wh) ? book.netbooked : 0}.sum
      style_warehouse_bookings[wh] = total_netbooked
    end
    s.update(warehouse_netbooked: "#{style_warehouse_bookings}")
  end
end
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: There are still 1000 updates here, and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you have for a single style, you are fetching booking with 3 type of warehouses finding sum of netbooked for each type of warehouse. This is highly inefficient.

One good rule is, first fetch required data from database, and after fetching data use ruby to handle data. It's important to fetch only required data. So, in your case, you can fetch styles and all related bookings. Then you can iterate through collection of bookings and prepare `style_warehouse_bookings` hash.

- use `find_each` instead of `each`
- use `includes` or `preload` to preload data.

Here is simple example which will definitely improve performance,

```
warehouses = ["WH1","WH2","WH3"]
#  preload bookings with style, `preload` used explicitely instead of `includes` to prevent cross join queries.
styles = Style.joins(:bookings).where('bookings.warehouse' => warehouses).preload(:bookings)
# find_each fetches data in batches of 1000 records
styles.find_each do |s|
  style_warehouse_bookings = Hash.new
  warehouses.each do |wh|
    # select and sum methods of ruby are used instead of where and sum of active-record
    total_netbooked = s.bookings.select{ |booking| booking.warehouse = wh }.sum(&:netbooked)
    style_warehouse_bookings[wh] = total_netbooked
  end
  s.update(warehouse_netbooked: "#{style_warehouse_bookings}")
end
```

Read in depth about `preload`, `includes` and `joins` at [eager loading associations documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). Apart from that I wrote an article on when to use `preload`, `includes` and `joins` [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/n-1-when-more-queries-is-a-good-thing/) which can help.

Comment: There are still 1000 updates here, and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: @EricDuminil thanks for pointing out typo. Read your comment, in question, but to remove 1000 updates, some entirely different approach might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do batch update. If I am correct check the following
link

[Is there anything like batch update in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694498/is-there-anything-like-batch-update-in-rails)

Also you can introduce transaction to avoid too many commits
For example

```
def assign_warehouse_bookings
    Style.transaction do 
         <your remaining code goes here>
    end
end
```

Comment: Just wanted to know, using transaction will reduce update queries to single or execute all update together?

Comment: Transaction will not reduce to single query but it will not add multiple commits. 

I think the link which I shared for batch update may help

Comment: yes it helped. Wrapping into transaction will commit transaction only once instead of committing every time update query is fired. This will give good performance boost.

Comment: yes.. but batch update still fires multiple queries.