# Rails - Update Multiple Records with one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel like I am missing something very obvious and simple here.  I have not seen any recent posts on this topic in years and my google searches are coming up short.  I am trying to Update multiple records at once from one form. I am using Rails 7.0.4

VIEW (form):

```
<%= form_with url: stats_update_path(params[:id], params[:team_id]) do |form| %>
<table class="min-w-full text-left text-sm">
    <tr class="">
      <td>#</td>    
      <td>Name</td>    
      <td>FGM</td>    
      <td>FGA</td>
    </tr>
    <% @roster.each_with_index do |player, index| %>
    <% player_stats = Stat.where("schedule_id = ? and team_id = ? and player_sport_id = ?", @schedule.id, params[:team_id], player.id).first %>
       <%= fields_for "stats[]" do |stats| %>
       <tr class="">
         <td><%= player.number %></td>    
         <td><%= player.player.name %></td>
         <td><%= stats.text_field :fgm, id: "fgm#{index}", value: player_stats.fgm %></td>
         <td><%= stats.text_field :fga, id: "fga#{index}", value: player_stats.fga%></td>
         <%= stats.hidden_field :id, id: "id#{index}", value: player_stats.id %>
         <%= stats.hidden_field :team_id, id: "team_id#{index}", value: params[:team_id] %>
         <%= stats.hidden_field :schedule_id, id: "schedule_id#{index}", value: @schedule.id %>
         <%= stats.hidden_field :player_sport_id, id: "player_sport_id#{index}", value: player.id %>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
</table>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
def edit
  @schedule = Schedule.find(params\[:id\])
  @roster = PlayerSport.includes(:player).where("team_id = ? and active = ?", params\[:team_id\], 1)
  @stats = Stat.where("team_id = ? and schedule_id = ?", params\[:team_id\], params\[:schedule_id\])
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
  if Stat.update(id: stats_params)
     format.html { redirect_to schedule_url(game.sport_id), notice: "Stat was successfully updated." }
     format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @stat }
  else
     format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     format.json { render json: @stat.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
end

\*\*\*\*THIS IS MY CREATE METHOD AND IT WORKS PERFECTLY
def create
   if stats_params.present?  
      respond_to do |format|
        if Stat.create(stats_params)
          format.html { redirect_to stat_url(game.sport_id), notice: "Stat was successfully created." }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stat }
        else
          format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          format.json { render json: @stat.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
   end
end

def stats_params
   params.permit(stats: [:id, :schedule_id, :team_id, :player_sport_id, :fga, :fgm]).require(:stats)
end
```

I know the problem is here

```
if Stat.update(id: stats_params)
```

in the `update` method.

I am not sure of the correct syntax or what exactly this update is doing. I do know that it produces an SQL statement like the one below, but it is obviously not what I am looking for. I have several attributes I need to update and id shouldn't be NULL.

```
UPDATE stats SET stats.id = NULL, stats.updated_at = '2024-02-27 04:43:28' WHERE stats.id = 1
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Jeff

I have tried several different syntax versions of the `Stat.update` line in the `update` method

Comment: Your question probably has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694498/is-there-anything-like-batch-update-in-rails/28695476#28695476)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can update multiple rows with a single command in Rails**, regardless of the method of collecting data.

First solution is pretty ancient, works in Rails 4 and probably earlier, not sure how many SQL statements it generates. Nevertheless, it runs validations and you can also wrap it in transaction manually if needed:

```rb
data = [{id: 1, status: 'approved'}, {id: 2, status: 'rejected'}]
for_update = data.index_by{ |e| e[:id] }
# { 1 => { :id => 1, :status => "approved" }, 2 => { :id => 2, :status => "rejected" } }
Task.update(for_update.keys, for_update.values)
```

Another option is to generate `ON CONFLICT` statement, because Rails 7 supports it

```rb
Task.upsert_all(
  [
    { id: 1, status: 'approved' },
    { id: 2, status: 'rejected' },
  ],
  unique_by: :id,
  update_only: [:status]
)
```

I have not checked whether it allows `:id` but considering the fact that primary key is basically a unique index on a table this should also work.

Comment: Thank you Nick.  I like the ON CONFLICT option.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Update line from

```
if Stat.update(id: stats_params)
```

to

```
if Stat.update(params[:stats].keys, params[:stats].values)
```

which fixed the problem and allows me to update now.

BUT

I had to alter my strong parameters.  Does this make sense?  Am I still protected if I am using permit!

```
def stats_params
  if params[:stats].is_a? Array
    params.permit(stats: [:schedule_id, :team_id, :player_sport_id, :fga, :fgm]).require(:stats)
  else
    params.require(:stats).permit!
  end
end
```

How can I add my attributes in the strong parameters if it is a hash like this? The "13" and "14" are dynamic and always changing depending on the player.

```
"stats"=>
  {"13"=> 
  {"fgm"=>"1",
     "fga"=>"1",
     "team_id"=>"20",
     "schedule_id"=>"154",
     "player_sport_id"=>"1"},
   "14"=>
    {"fgm"=>"0",
     "fga"=>"0",
     "team_id"=>"20",
     "schedule_id"=>"154",
     "player_sport_id"=>"2"}
```

Comment: Your answer seems to introduce another question. I would suggest opening a new topic for that after search for existing issues.